# Twitter-Bootstrap tabs load container content via AJAX

Tags: ajax, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement this example for Twitter-Bootstrap tabs http://www.dba-resources.com/scripting-programming/ajax-tabs-in-bootstrap-2-1/ loading content via AJAX, but I need to load the content from a div container within the same document, rather than loading multiple documents. The code I'm using is as follows:

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $("#MainTabs").tab();
    $("#MainTabs").bind("show", function(e) {    
        var contentID  = $(e.target).attr("data-target");
        var contentURL = $(e.target).attr("href");
        if (typeof(contentURL) != 'undefined')
            $(contentID).load(contentURL, function(){ $("#MainTabs").tab(); });
        else
            $(contentID).tab('show');
        });
    $('#MainTabs div[data-target="#tabone"]').tab("show");
});
```

HTML

```
<ul id="MainTabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><div data-target="#tabone" data-toggle="tab">tab One</div></li>
    <li><div data-target="#tabtwo" data-toggle="tab" href="/test.html">Tab Two</div></li>
    <li><div data-target="#tabthree" data-toggle="tab" href="/test2.html">Tab Three</div></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tabone">Content Tab One</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tabtwo">Loading...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tabthree">Loading...</div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 7):

That should be the default behavior if you just pass in the `id` of the container to the `href`.

```
<li><div data-target="#tabone" data-toggle="tab" href="#loadedcontent">tab One</div></li>

....

<div id="loadedcontent">My content</div>
```

Since you have a special case where you want to load a specific container of the page through an AJAX call. You can do something like this.

**HTML**

```
<li><div id="specialTab" data-target="#tabone" data-toggle="tab" href="/ajax.html">tab one</div></li>
```

**JS**

```
$('#specialTab').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var containerId = '#content'; /** Specify which element container */
    var self = $(this);
    var url = self.attr('href');
    $(self.data('target'))
        .load(url +' '+ containerId, function(){
           self.tab('show');
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Denise. The need is to load a specific container (div) from an external file. The default behavior is not what I need.

Comment: Thanks again. So in this case what would be the code for tabtwo to load yet a different container inside /ajax.html? Say #contenttwo. Each tab would load a different container from the same external html

Comment: In that case, you can make the `<div class="specialTab" data-container="#container" data-toggle="tab" href="/ajax.html"></div>` and the `data-container` would specify the element you want to capture. You would then replace the `var containerId=self.data('container');` to get the container element.