# Bootstrap tables, load from url - remove dom after change

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Greetings im struggeling with a small issue, each time I open a tab it add's the content to the whole html document, so for example if I open 3 tabs at once, I will get all the html data inside the tab div's content, but what I want to achieve is just to have 1 populated div with the data. It is mostlikely Jquery relevant question - and everything works fine apart of my question. My solution would be - onclick->load my desired tab->remove the content from the other containers, but how to write it?

Jquery code that manipulates the data

```
 $('#myTabs a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
        var href = this.hash;
        var pane = $(this);
               $.blockUI({ 
    message: '<img src="<?PHP echo base_url();?>assets/images/load.gif" alt="Loading" /> Loading...' }); 

        $(href).load(url,function(result){      
            pane.tab('show');

            $.unblockUI();
        });
    });
```

Block representing the tab selection

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs">
        <li><a href="#data1" data-url="<?PHP echo base_url();?>Klienci/Profil/<?PHP echo $this->uri->segment(3);?>/DK">Client data1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#data2" data-url="<?PHP echo base_url();?>Klienci/Profil/<?PHP echo $this->uri->segment(3);?>/OK">Client data2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#data3" data-url="<?PHP echo base_url();?>Klienci/Profil/<?PHP echo $this->uri->segment(3);?>/PR">Client data3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#data4" data-url="<?PHP echo base_url();?>Klienci/Profil/<?PHP echo $this->uri->segment(3);?>/ZG">Client data4</a></li>
      </ul>
```

The containers for corespodning tabs

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="data1"></div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="data2"></div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="data3"></div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="data4"></div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719747/twitter-bootstrap-tabs-load-container-content-via-ajax

Answer (score 0):

to write to the tab, you need to write the `html` into it. With jQuery it will be:

```
$tabPaneSelector.html(resultHtml);
```